# Is it possible to wear two hats?

Tags: support, winter-bash

When I wear one hat, and then click on another hat, the first one is removed.

Is there any button like "preserve hat", or something else I'm not seeing?

Comment: There is [a hack](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ5HK.png). Hint: http://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Comment: Do you wear two hats in every day life ;)

Comment: @SethMcClaine. But some hats don't looks hats here

Comment: It wasn't really an argument @WashingtonGuedes

Comment: I love this question.  LOL!  Why stop at 2!

Answer (score 27):

No; you only get one hat at at time.

If you want two hats, you can always take a cropped screenshot of your avatar wearing *one* hat, then place the other one on your avatar anywhere else.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure why anyone would want a gravatar with more than one hat.

However, if you were so inclined... I would suggest getting the image itself, and then modifying it as opposed to using a screenshot. This will retain the pixel quality of the image.

[image]

<sub>* contains hats from years prior: fake secret megatron hat under a boba fet mask hat with unicorn hat, jeff atwood hair hat, scuba hat, earphone hat, and the bow for rep cap hat.</sub>

Comment: For a mashup, that's quite majestic.

Comment: @SterlingArcher - What can I say... I love hats :P

Comment: I'm sorry, I never took a look at your large avatar. Always when I looked at your small avatar, I thought you were a clown wearing a storm trooper helmet :p

Answer (score 3):

No, you can only wear one hat at a time.

I did propose to have other pieces of clothing as part of last years [Closing remarks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246542/158100) but that feature request didn't make it.